# How to return the full document using xdmp:node-replace()?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a requirement where i need to return the full document at last after all the process completes.

My Last statement is having an `xdmp:node-replace()` and hence it is returning an `empty sequence`.

The nodes are getting replaced in my final document but i am not able to see them on console in 1st run. When i am running it second time then i can able to see the replaced node.

Here is the sample code-

```
abc.xml--->
  <root>
       <id>abcd</id>
  </root>

let $doc := doc("abc.xml")
 (: Let $doc is having an Id node :)

let $replace := xdmp:node-replace($doc//id,<id>1234</id>)
  return $doc

Actual Output-->
 <root>
       <id>abcd</id>
  </root>

 Expected Output-->
   <root>
       <id>1234</id>
  </root>
```

If i will return `$replace` then it will give me `empty sequence`

I want to return the expected output in 1st run

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdmp:node-replace` replaces nodes in database, not in-memory. Also you cannot see database updates before a commit.

A simple solution would be to create a updated in-memory document and return that.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("abc.xml",
<root>
  <id>abcd</id>
  <name>Test</name>
</root>
);

let $doc := doc("abc.xml")
let $update := 
<root>
    <id>1234</id>
    {$doc/root/name}
</root>

return (
  xdmp:document-insert("abc.xml", $update), 
  $update
)
```

Edit:

Alternative using a in-memory replace function:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';

let $doc := doc("abc.xml")
let $updatedDoc := mem:node-replace($doc//id, <id>1234</id>)

return (
  xdmp:node-replace($doc, $updatedDoc),
  $updatedDoc
)
```

Performance-wise i think mine and Mads Hansen's alternatives share the same performance characteristics. I'd say choose whatever you like most.
I have used my approach for simple update use cases alot, for more complicated use cases which might also involve moving nodes or so, i'd rather use Mads Hansen's XSLT alternative.

Comment: This answer is basically correct.  xdmp:node-replace() is a state-setting function which returns nothing.  So this answer is equivalent to

`let $doc := doc("abc.xml")

return xdmp:node-replace($doc//id,<id>1234</id>)`

and then in a new transaction, `doc("abc.xml")` to see the changed doc

Comment: @Wargner Michael-- Thank you it helps me. So basically wherever i want to return the document structure during any `node operation` then i can return the `mem` document instead ? It won't create performance issues ?

Comment: I don't see a problem returning the in-memory document. Also this should not create any performance issues. Edited my answer for another alternative you might want to use.

Comment: @WagnerMichael Thanks ! That helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for modifying in-memory would be via XSLT. Using an identity transformation, create templates to match the node(s) that you want to change:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $XSLT := 
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id/text()">
        <xsl:text>1234</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>;

let $doc := doc("abc.xml")
let $modified := xdmp:xslt-eval($XSLT, $doc)
return 
  ( xdmp:node-replace($doc, $modified), $modified )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-statement transaction, [using a semi-colon](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_41212) to separate the write transaction from the read transaction, so that you can see the update.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:node-replace(doc("abc.xml")//id, <id>1234</id>)
;

xquery version "1.0-ml";
doc("abc.xml")
```

Comment: When i try to use semicolon `;` it gives me `Unxpected Token Syntax Error` and asks- did you mean comma `,`

Comment: No, a `;`. It sounds like you may have one too many somewhere. Are you running the code that I posted, or did you apply to another module that may have additional `;` somewhere?

Comment: @Mads-- I am applying it to one of my XQuery module but it is not having any `;` except at top where i am declaring `variables` and `importing` namespaces.

Comment: It says we cannot use `;` operator in XQuery to terminate a line